# STM32 Nucleo F401RE in Arduino IDE - how to enable more than 1 Serial?

Tags: serial

I just received a Nucleo F401RE and can't get my sketch to work on it because the compiler says Serial1 is not defined.
My sketch uses multiple serials because I need to use the usb serial monitor while also communicating to another device on a different serial port.

Here is a screenshot of the flags I selected.

[image: compiling flags]

According to the F401 specs it has at least 6 different serials, so the real question is: is there an easy way to use Serial1 and so on straight out of the box in the Arduino IDE?

I'm quite new and unexperienced to this field, so please excuse me if this question is too trivial.

Comment: http://www.stm32duino.com/

Comment: could you elaborate more, please? I've looked for an answer on stm32duino.com forum before posting here, but couldn't find any. I also wanted to post my question there, but it seems like it's impossible to register as a new user, so I'm stranded at the moment

Comment: the options from Tools menu are evaluated in WSerial.h. SerialUSB and/or Serial are defined. the way described in answer is the right one to create additional Serial interfaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frederic Pillon on Github has been very helpful and suggested me the solution, which is to define the serial via:

```
HardwareSerial Serial1(PA10, PA9);
```

instead of just giving Serial1 for granted as you would do on a regular Arduino mega